# Analog of class view in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to quickly navigate through large files with multiple functions?
Something like class view in VS ?

Comment: There is now an Outline panel, that shows the `gotoSymbol` data as a tree.  This should be a tab in the Explorer panel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is the `workbench.action.gotoSymbol` command also known as *outlining*. Its default shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

If you have an extension installed which supports this command for the current file type then a list of methods, classes and maybe other symbols for the current file will drop down which allows you to jump to their definitions.

Comment: have you seen a GUI extension, by chance?

Comment: I hope this is not against the rules, but I found this extension really useful. I think it fits what the OP needs. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline

Comment: @finnTheHumin this extension is deprecated : ⚠️ DEPRECATED. Please use the Outline view that comes with Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is now a built-in [Outline View](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view)  in VS CODE

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a **built-in Outline View** in Vscode *(as other answer said)*
2. There is also **[outline-map]** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gerrnperl.outline-map

   - it collapses the object/hierarchy **automatically**, & expands as you scroll to it.

     (*recommended*, more usable than the built-in one)
3. (or just find other ones in Vscode Extension **Marketplace**)